# How possible sign user in Robo test from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I want add Robo test to my project. I need that testbot can sign-in in app.
In documentation [https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-ux-test#sign-in] I fount information. that for custom sign-in i must add editTextViewResIds for login, password and value. I do it and run test. 
But in results that robot don't this values, and and don't go to any screen fro authorize user. 
Do you have any ideas what I do wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mind clarifying - are you using a Robo script or Robo directives? Also, it would help if you provide more details on what Robo behavior you observe and what behavior you expect. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know exactly. I select "Run robo test" and  don't add custom robo script. I observe how robot test login and registration screen. I expect that on logon screen for login and password field will be used presetted value

Comment: You are using Robo directives. A Robo directive is applied only if Robo reaches a screen that contains the UI element a Robo directive operates on (e.g., a login text field). If during the crawl Robo never encounters a screen with the Robo directive's UI element, the Robo directive is never applied. You can see which Robo directives have not been applied during a crawl on the 'Robo' tab of the test results page.

If you see that Robo does visit a screen where a Robo directive should be applied, but still does not apply it, double check the resource id of your Robo directive.